# VueJS <h4> auto nextline not working with computed properties

Tags: css, vue.js

I am currently using a computed prop to return a interpolated string to render below is an example of my code:-

```
<div class="productDetailContainer">
  <nuxt-link :to="{ path: '/product/sidebar/' + product.shortName }">
    <h4 class="productName">{{ product.name }}</h4>
  </nuxt-link>
  <h4 class="productPrice">
    {{ priceRange }} <------------------ THIS LINE
  </h4>
</div>

priceRange() {
  const { product } = this;

  if (product.price.lowest !== product.price.highest) {
    return `RM${product.price.lowest.toFixed(
      2
    )}~RM${product.price.highest.toFixed(2)}`;
  }
  return `RM${product.price.highest.toFixed(2)}`
},
```

[image: Using "priceRange" computed props]

But if I change the {{priceRange}} to lorem ipsum then h4 will automatically break to nextline if the text overflows as the picture below:-

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first example overflow doesn't occur because there are no whitespaces in the string. But there are whitespaces in the second example.
If you want to avoid line break, just add a CSS rule for the container
`white-space: nowrap;`

Comment: oh wow what a newbie mistake I did there... thanks man its working now !